# /~/software/ParticleRuntime/v84/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

I'm very new to Linux, and am trying to make curl work on Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14) for some shell script to work. I'm getting the error message

> /~/software/ParticleRuntime/v84/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4: no version
>   information available (required by curl)

I've had a look in the forums and it seems there may be an issue with multiple versions of curl being installed, when I try and locate libcurl:

```
locate libcurl.so.4
```

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0

But I don't really know where to go from here. In the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory is

libcurl-gnutls.so.3

libcurl-gnutls.so.4

libcurl-gnutls.so.4.3.0

libcurl.so.3

and in the /~/software/ParticleRuntime/v84/bin/glnxa64 folder is

libcurl.so.4 and libcurl.so.4.2.0.

Sorry if this is basic, I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue & used below steps to solve :

**1. First locate the location of libcurl**:

```
locate libcurl.so.4
```

Probably like this

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
```

**2. Deleted the soft link for this conflict**

```
 rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

**3.Then, link the 4.3.0 static library to the top**

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply... when I locate libcurl, I only actually have the top two locations:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0, not the bottom two - I'm not sure why this is, and as a result the fix doesn't work... any ideas?!!